# sql searching multiple words in a string

Tags: sql

What is the most efficient and elegant **SQL query looking for a string containing the words "David", "Moses" and "Robi"**. Assume the table is named T and the column C.

Comment: Depends on the SQL Dialect. Which server?

Comment: Are you looking to match all three words in the same field or just return all rows that match any one of the three? I read it as matching _all_, but it looks like many people interpreted it as _any_.

Comment: What RDBMS?  Do you want to know if the same row in the column contains all three, or just that the column itself contains all 3 on some number of rows?  What's the structure of the data, are they single names or do we need to account for additional string data?  What's the actual data type?  Do we need to worry about foreign language characters as well as latin?  **Someone who has asked 34 questions probably should know what information to provide.**

Comment: Thank you all. For some reason the exact same wording with no clarifications sufficed for a friend of mine who's a DBA to provide me my answer. Thank you for you trouble. 

@Wiseguy - My original wording was exact, but @hamlin11 edited it, possibly making it unclear as you said. Though I'm sure he meant well.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
Select * from table where 
  columnname like'%David%' and 
  columnname like '%Moses%' and columnname like'%Robi%'
```

Comment: the second query is correct and searches the string for the keyword whereas the first query just retrieve values with those specific word

Comment: If you care about the sequence of the terms, you may consider using a syntax like
`select * from T where C like'%David%Moses%Robi%'`

Comment: If you are using a join query and need to look for multiple strings in the same column, put parentheses that encompass the common ANDs

Answer (score 30):

In SQL Server 2005+ with Full-Text indexing switched on, I'd do the following:

```
SELECT *
  FROM T
 WHERE CONTAINS(C, '"David" OR "Robi" OR "Moses"');
```

If you wanted your search to bring back results where the result is prefixed with David, Robi or Moses you could do:

```
SELECT *
  FROM T
 WHERE CONTAINS(C, '"David*" OR "Robi*" OR "Moses*"');
```

Comment: The way I understand the question, you'd want `AND`s instead of `OR`s -- which also means that multiple prefixes wouldn't make sense, but thanks for adding that info.

Comment: Free Text Searching / Indexing is absolute rubbish - using this and as the index does not rebuild straight away - e.g. Auto tracking still only builds every 30 min, so using this and all you will get is angry customers who cannot find what they just entered.

Answer (score 8):

If you care about the sequence of the terms, you may consider using a syntax like

```
select * from T where C like'%David%Moses%Robi%'
```

Comment: How about the scenario if you don't care about the sequence?

Comment: In this case see the accepted answer above

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I uses to search for multiple words in multiple columns - SQL server

Hope my answer help someone :) Thanks

```sql
declare @searchTrm varchar(MAX)='one two three ddd 20   30 comment'; 
--select value from STRING_SPLIT(@searchTrm, ' ') where trim(value)<>''
select * from Bols 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT value  
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@searchTrm, ' ')  
    WHERE 
        trim(value)<>''
        and(    
        BolNumber like '%'+ value+'%'
        or UserComment like '%'+ value+'%'
        or RequesterId like '%'+ value+'%' )
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

**Oracle SQL :**

```
select * 
from MY_TABLE
where REGEXP_LIKE (company , 'Microsodt industry | goglge auto car | oracles    database')
```

- company - is the database column name.
- results - this SQL will show you if company column rows contain one of those companies (OR phrase) 
  please note that : no wild characters are needed, it's built in.

more info at : http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/regexp_like.php

Answer (score 1):

if you put all the searched words in a temporaray table say @tmp and column col1, then you could try this:

```
Select * from T where C like (Select '%'+col1+'%' from @temp);
```

Comment: First, mark your code as code. Second it won't work, at least not with SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @sara: I just have tested it in sql server 2008 R2

Comment: I tried this, and i get "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >="

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `EXISTS` can help.

```
and exists (select 1 from @DocumentNames where pcd.Name like DocName+'%' or CD.DocumentName like DocName+'%')
```

Answer (score -5):

Oracle SQL:
There is the "IN" Operator in Oracle SQL which can be used for that:

```
select 
    namet.customerfirstname, addrt.city, addrt.postalcode
from schemax.nametable namet
join schemax.addresstable addrt on addrt.adtid = namet.natadtid
where namet.customerfirstname in ('David', 'Moses', 'Robi');
```