# Need to find result from multiple string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below is my table output. I wanted to find the result with using multiple string that contains in the result.

for example: I need to get result that contain ["how", "are", "you"]

```
column A
-----------------
how are you?
How about you?
how are you going?
how are you doing?
What up?
What is up?
Are you alright?
```

Comment: Does the result has to contain all the 3 words or just one of those words ?

Comment: Need to know both the query 1) With anyone word 2) With all the words

Comment: you can create dynamic query with conditions joined by OR

Comment: As Tim said in comments to deleted answer, you can use full text search https://stackoverflow.com/a/6506489/7974050

Comment: select * from tablename where [column A] like '%how%' or [column A] like '%are%' or [column A] like '%you%'

Answer (score 1):

Any one of the words

```
select * from tablename where [column A] like '%how%' or [column A] like '%are%' or [column A] like '%you%'
```

All the words

```
select * from tablename where [column A] like '%how%' and [column A] like '%are%' and [column A] like '%you%'
```

All the words together

```
select * from tablename where [column A] like '%how are you%'
```